# List of common bitmask values for PHP errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Can someone please provide a list of the numbers we need to use to configure php error reporting levels in an Apache vhost? I think they're called "bitmask"s or something, but I cant find a list of them anywhere.

ie in Apache:

```
php_value error_reporting x
```

What should x be if I want the equivalent of:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

And since there's no reference on this anywhere online (that I can find), let's do the rest too!

E_ALL = x

E_NOTICE = y

E_WARNING = z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [**this**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) what you're looking for ?

**EDIT**

The values listed in the table pointed to above are the ones that you want. You will note that with the exception of E_ALL they are all powers of 2. Each of the values corresponds to a bit position in an integer. Adding the values of these bit positions together gives the value that you want in your vhost definition e.g.

if you want error reporting for `E_ERROR` `E_NOTICE` and `E_USER_WARNING`

```
Constant            Value         Binary

E_ERROR               1                1
E_NOTICE              8             1000
E_USER_WARNING      512       1000000000

Total               521       1000001001
```

So the value to use in your vhost `php_value error_reporting` directive would be 521.

Comment: +1 for going straight to the source.

Comment: No, those pre-defined constants only work in PHP, and the page doesn't explain how to combine them to get the value you want. It says the bitwise operators only work in PHP.ini, but I need a single numeric value for an Apache vhost.

Comment: You combine them by adding them together to get the value that you want.

Why the down vote ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was trying to figure out how to get the integer value, and the PHP manual doesn't explain that very well.